# Copy Headers from an excel file (Excel VBA code)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Good Morning!

I am working on an excel file in which I want to copy headers from one sheet and paste it after headers of another sheet. An example is:

The sheet 1 has data headers as:
[image]

Sheet 2 has data headers as:
[image]

The issue is that the number of headers in both doesnt remian constant each month. So I want thye code (VBA) to copy headers starting from A1 to last used cell of sheet2 and paste it after last used cell of sheet1. Here is the code that I have written to the best of my knowledge about VBA:

```
Sub LastColumnInOneRow()
'Find the last used column in a Row: row 1 in this example
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim LastCell As String
    Dim last As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    With Sheets("Data")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set rng = Sheets("Data").Cells
LastCell = last(3, rng)
Range("A1" & LastCell).Select
 Selection.Copy
End With
End Sub
```

I know there is something wrong with this code as it doesn run. Can anyone help with with this problem.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: well, your *With* block is missing it's *end with* and your line **LastCell=last(3,rng)** looks wrong too unless there is a function called *last* that I don't know! Take a look at my code answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below:

```
Sub LastColumnInOneRow()

Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range

sheets("Sheet2").select
Set rngSource = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column))
rngsource.copy

sheets("Sheet1").select
Set rngDestination = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)

' rngSource.Copy Destination:=rngDestination
'    rngDestination.pastespecial xlpasteall
rngDestination.select
activesheet.paste
End Sub
```

that should get you started

Philip

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code is giving an error; "Object requiredd" and highlights this line of the code: Set rngSource = Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), Sheet2.Cells(1, Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column)).

Comment: You should use "Dim Sheet2 as Worksheet, Set Sheet2 = Sheets("enter_your_sheetname_here") and it should be fine.

Also i would suggest using Cells(1,columns.count).end(xlToLeft).column as your way will not work if there are empty column headers

Comment: yes, sheet2/sheet1 is the ID or reference in the VB Editor - Project Explorer (use CTRL-R to show), if that has been renamed for any reason then instead of Sheet2, use **sheets("Sheet2")** and instead of sheet1 use **sheets(Sheet1")**

Comment: +1 @PotterRafed I have modified the code to make it easier for you to step through the code using F8 and see what is going on

Comment: Thank you. The code is running perfect. The only issue is that whenver a column heading is in merged cells in Sheet1, it starts pasting the headers from Sheet2 at merged cell on sheet1.